# How can I use the existing firebase-ios-sdk dependency in my native swift code?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I am working on a Flutter app that uses the FlutterFire firebase_messaging package.

I need to add delivery reports to my app, but the FlutterFire library does not support this.

So I must implement [this native swift code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#enable-message-delivery-data-export).

But for this code to compile I must add the firebase-ios-sdk package to my 'Runner' project.

When building I now get the error...

```
Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase'
```

Because both my Runner project and the FlutterFire dependency are both including the firebase-ios-sdk.

How can I import FirebaseMessaging in native swift code, while using the firebase-ios-sdk dependency that FlutterFire already imports?

If I try to add a library dependency from the existing flutter dependency (I go to General > Library Dependency > select "Pods > firebase_messaging"), the swift code is not able to resolve the 'import FirebaseMessaging' statement.

Comment: you have firebase messaging in flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/install
if you want to use in appdelegate you must add it to pubspec.yaml and just use it to appdelegate, but you must have a copy from appdelegate.

Comment: clone `FlutterFire` and add your code in that package and refer cloned package in pubspec.yaml file.
Now FlutterFire contain your code as well as FlutterFire original code

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

add your firebase package to pubspec.yaml

such as :

```
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.14
```

[image]

after that if you want to add "[this native swift code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#enable-message-delivery-data-export)" implementation you must just import below to AppDelegate file:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
```

and

```
Messaging.serviceExtension().exportDeliveryMetricsToBigQuery(withMessageInfo:request.content.userInfo)
```

instead of

```
Messaging.extensionHelper()
      .exportDeliveryMetricsToBigQuery(withMessageInfo:request.content.userInfo)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me because my swift code is in a new App Extension target. Add a new target App Extension of type notification service extension, and try. This approach should not work in this case.

Comment: @Scorb you didn't mention it in the question.